# Advice about letting UI person style our web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, responsive-design, user-experience

So we have created a small website in Asp.net MVC and now it is time to let the UI person do their magic. Obviously we can't give a third-party UI person the whole Visual Studio solution and ask them to style just the .cshtml views for us, that would be stupid because code may be stolen, cloned, end up on the web somewhere by accident, etc. 
So the objective and the thoughts are below:

**Objective:**

1. Let the third-party UI person apply styles to .cshtml files to make it look pretty for desktop and mobile devices without giving that UI person entire code for the solution and protecting our IP in the application DLL files.
2. Make it easy for UI person edit and test .cshtml files when they are styling our application

**Thoughts that we had:**

1. Host application on a server and give the UI person read/write access only to the Views folder and the Content folder (for css/js) via FTP. This way a UI person should be able to apply styles to the .cshtml files without getting access to the DLL's. The problem with this approach is that person can still write & execute C# code in the .cshtml view itself, potentially writing code to upload dlls to a third party location, browse directories, etc. So this still doesn't quite seems like a flexible and secure solution.
2. Use method from above and also obfuscate dlls to lessen the chances of dlls, and any other files being views or compromised by C# code execution that can be done from .cshtml files.

So that's about all that we have came up with so far. The idea is really to protect our IP that is basically DLL files that contain our custom application logic, while giving the UI person as much flexibility and comfort as possible to perform their work.

Any ideas and thoughts would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a framework like Bootstrap (or any other UI framework) and have your UI person design a theme for that framework?

Comment: copyright your stuff, and make it clear in their contract that you'll sue if they steal or leak your data. Same as I would imagine you'd do with a regular employee. Then give them the best tools to do their job efficiently. Maybe consider asking them what access they actually need in order to work properly. This isn't really a programming question, it's a legal and bureaucratic issue

Comment: Unfortunately such a question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's an opinion-solicitation question. There's no right answer to this, and Stack Overflow doesn't support general discussion.

Answer (score -1):

How about writing a new mvc project that only returns predefinded static data in a similar manor you application would, effectively a stub that they can code against. Then you can lift the views etc and place in your main project.

Ideally (although a little late I guess now) I'd  separate the layers and have a service layer that returns data to the presentation layer. Then you can give them full access to the presentation layer without them seeing anything in the lower layers. Some general blurb on this practice [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)